# Communicating with micro USB to Ethernet

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb, tethering

I am trying to communicate with an ethernet enabled devices from my Android phone. My phone has **Android 2.3.6** and the device I am trying to communicate with has a mini web server running on it. The device has a single RJ45 port for communication with the outside word. Is it possible for me to connect my Android phone using a  micro usb to Ethernet adapter and talk to the mini web server? If so, could you kindly show me how to go about this.

I have connected my **Nexus One**  and tried to enable USB tethering but it doesn't work. I was reading an article on ADB but it doesn't show how to establish connection and assign address to an adapter.

Comment: Does your Nexus One recognize the ethernet adapter? Do you have a wired router? Could you plug the mini web server and phone into a router? (This would allow DHCP to assign IPs and then you would have a way to communicate.)

Comment: The Nexus One does not seem to be recognizing the ethernet adapter. Is there any other Andriod Phone that allows this? For my class design project, we need to only communicate via wire directly with the phone. One of the constrains is that, no wifi or cellular connection can be used. So, in short, we can only use the micro usb to ethernet adapter and connect directly to the device. If there is any other android base device that I can use, please let me know. For now, I already had a Nexus One so we decided to use it

Comment: Is your device rooted? With a terminal emulator you could set a static ip for the ethernet adapter that is in the same subnet as the server.

Comment: Yes the phone is rooted. I tried ifconfig usb0 192.168.x.x  but it didn't work. I was able to log into the shell using adb when I connected the micro usb to USB cable directly to my laptop. Is there another way you recommend?

Comment: It's more likely to be eth0 instead of usb0. Give that a try.

Comment: From the terminal using netcfg, eth0 doesn't show up. however, i did try and nothing seem to happen as eth0 wasn't present. Meanwhile, I just tried rebooting the phone and it is no longer powering on. I have tried fastboot but it states that the device is offline

Comment: You might be able to connect a router with USB port to the rj45 on the web server then connect the phone to the USB port on the router.

Comment: See also: [How to use an USB-attached wired Ethernet adapter through USB-OtG on an Android smartphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/53443/1465)

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)